# How to append to list within multilevel dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm traversing through a file and want to build a dynamic dictionary of multiple levels. The last level needs to store a list of values.

```
myDict = defaultdict(dict)

for key in lvlOneKeys: # this I know ahead of time so I set up my dictionary with first level. I'm not sure if this is necessary.
    myDict[key] = {}

with open(myFile, "rb") as fh:
    for line in fh:
        # found something, which will match lvlOneKey and dynamically determine lvlTwoKey and valueFound
        # ...
        myDict[lvlOneKey][lvlTwoKey].append(valueFound)
```

I need to do this because lvlTwoKey will be found multiple times with different valueFound's.

Unfortunately this code results in a KeyError for lvlOneKey. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Some sample inputs and expected outputs will probably help you get some better answers.

Comment: have you tried: `myDict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))`

Comment: @jp_data_analysis `defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))` would make more sense, wouldn't it?

Comment: in the code you never set `[lvlTwoKey]` to anything. It needs to be an empty list at least if you want to `append` to it. E.g. `if not myDict[lvlOneKey].get(lvlTwoKey, None): myDict[lvlOneKey][lvlTwoKey] = [valueFound] else: myDict[lvlOneKey][lvlTwoKey].append(valueFound)` happy to elaborate if this helps

Comment: @patrick I ended up using this method. It worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: @Colin Glad to hear it! I posted a more complete answer with more comments / background if you want to accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the code under the `for` loop with the following should solve your problem:

```
# if there is no `lvlTwoKey` in `myDict`, initialize a list with `valueFound` in it  
if not myDict[lvlOneKey].get(lvlTwoKey, None):
    myDict[lvlOneKey][lvlTwoKey] = [valueFound]
# otherwise, append to the existing list 
else: 
    myDict[lvlOneKey][lvlTwoKey].append(valueFound)
```

This uses the `get()` method on the dictionary, which you can read about [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get). Besides that, it's just a standard dictionary, which I find often to be more readable / intuitive than complex defaultdicts.

Answer (score 2):

This is an almost foolproof way of ensuring you won't get an error. The way we have defined `myDict`, you can have any keys for dictionary "level 1" and dictionary "level 2". By default, an empty list is assumed at the end of the dictionary tree.

```
myDict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

with open(myFile, "rb") as fh:
    for line in fh:
        # found something, which will match lvlOneKey and dynamically determine lvlTwoKey and valueFound
        # ...
        myDict[lvlOneKey][lvlTwoKey].append(valueFound)
```

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't want to do `from collections import defaultdict`, you can also do `myDict[lvlOneKey].setdefault(lvlTwoKey, list()).append(valueFound)` instead

Comment: I changed my first line to myDict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list)), but I still get the same key error...

Comment: @Colin, can you try printing the key just before it try to set it? I'm thinking (perhaps) it could be an invalid key.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis I checked the key value and it matches what I expect. I played around with it again and it looks like I have to remove `for key in lvlOneKeys: myDict[key] = {}`, after which it works.

Comment: @Colin, you are right, and this makes perfect sense - I have now amended the code.

Answer (score 0):

This can get a bit annoying if you get much further nested, but using this pattern will work.

```
l1keys = [1, 2, 1]
l2keys = ['foo', 'bar', 'spangle']

base = {}
for l1key, l2key in zip(l1keys, l2keys):
    for i in range(5):
        l1 = base.get(l1key, {})
        l2 = l1.get(l2key, [])
        l2.append(i)
        l1[l2key] = l2
        base[l1key] = l1

assert base == {
    1: {'foo': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'spangle': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]},
    2: {'bar': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]}
}
```